# Перенаправление на страницу авторизации

Tags: python, django

хотел узнать, как определить такое поведение сайта, чтобы при получении любой его страницы пользователь сразу перенаправлялся на страницу авторизации?

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/auth/default.html#auth-web-requests

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите, чтобы неавторизованные пользователи не могли получить доступ к определенной странице, перед ее функцией-представлением (view) используйте декоратор `@login_required` ([подробнее](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)), а перед классом-представлением – `@method_decorator(login_required, 'dispatch')`. Как вариант, можно включить в класс-представление наследование от `LoginRequiredMixin` ([подробнее](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)). Примеры ниже.

```py
# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


@login_required
def some_view(request):
    ...


class SomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
    ...
```

Узнайте больше в [официальной документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/)